# How to solve ambiguous function overload due to default constructor in parameter

Tags: c++, gcc, g++

Let's say I have this class:

```
class Foo {
public:
   void member(std::string s);
   void member(int64_t &n);
};
```

Now I want to do some thing like

```
int64_t value = 5;
Foo f;
f.member(value);
```

The problem is that the compiler (at least GCC) gets confused & believes I'm trying to call member with a string using the char* constructor:

```
invalid conversion from 'int64_t' to 'const char*
```

How could I go about calling the actual member function I want without changing the method signature?  Are templates the only solution?  I have tried casting without any help (which shouldn't matter since the type is already unambiguous).

---

Sorry - found the mistake.

The declaration was:

```
class Foo {
public:
    void member(std::string s);
    void member(int64_t &n);
};
```

Removing the by-ref solved it.

Comment: I can't reproduce the error with GCC 3.3, 4.2, or 4.4 on Ubuntu nor with GCC 3.4 on Solaris 10.

Comment: You're correct - for some reason, my attempts to reduce to a simple case failed.  It was a compiler error with my actual code though - maybe I missed something else.

Comment: Now with the change to `int64_t&` it doesn't make sense to me anymore why it should fail to compile.

Answer (score 5):

Cast the argument to exactly match the argument type of the overload you want:

```
f.member((int64_t) value);
```

Comment: That's redundant if you are already passing a variable with the correct type.

Comment: That won't work because he has a non-const reference parameter, though.

Comment: @unknown: But he is not passing the correct type. The parameter should be __int64_t__ he is passing __uint64_t__

Comment: Sorry - typo in the description.  That should have been int64_t.

Answer (score 0):

Sorry - found the mistake.

The declaration was:

```
class Foo {
public:
   void member(std::string s);
   void member(int64_t &n);
};
```

Removing the by-ref solved it.

Comment: You changed the method signature which you said you didn't want to do... ah well

Comment: Yeah, I guess.  I was thinking more along the lines of changing the function name.  It's still unclear to me why the compiler was getting confused (only in my code - my attempts to reduce the code to an example failed).

Answer (score -1):

There may be easier ways to solve this (like with a parameter cast) but I have seen solutions that look like the following:

```
void (Foo::*memberProc)(int64_t) = &Foo::member;

Foo f;
((f).*(memberProc))(5);
```

Convoluted, yes, but it's explicit.

Comment: Ugly. I would sooner slit my wrists than use such a solution.